# database select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. film(film_id, filmname) PK (film_id)
2. category(category_id, categoryname) PK (category_id)
3. film_category(contains both primary keys (film_id) and (category_id))

The problem is that I want to select all `filmname` from film tables where category_id = 3.

How to do this mysql select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  film.filmname
from
  film
  join film_category
  on film.film_id = film_category.film_id
where
  film_category.category_id = 3
```

[Further info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT filmname
FROM film NATURAL JOIN film_category
WHERE category_id = 3
```

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is the worst thing in ANSI-92 join syntax.

Comment: I normally agree. However, I'd never have `film_id` in `film`. Given the setup of the database, this is the most NATURAL way to write it. (sorry about the pun.)

Comment: @OMGPonies: Why? If table1 and table2 as natural connection (and only one, and it's defined in the DDL), why not using it for simplifing qureies?

Comment: @Y.Shoham: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039719/is-natural-join-considered-harmful-in-production-environment/6039758#6039758) is why.

Comment: @@Y.Shoham: Amadan beat me to it

Comment: @OMGPonies: I didn't mean that - I mean it's not DRY. I'd have `films (id, name)`, `film_categories (film_id, film_category_id)`, `film_categories (id, name)`. Only foreign keys deserve the table prefix.

Comment: Amadan: `id` column fails Spolsky's hallway test.  And it's not consistent if one column is `id` while the rest have a prefix that makes things very obvious.

Comment: @OMGPonies: How is `film_id` better than `films.id`? "The rest" don't have the prefix, only foreign keys do. `film_name` or `filmname` is equally noisy. In my view, if it has a prefix, it's a foreign key - look for its real value in the other table (and it's a natural read from `films.category_id`). `films.id` also reads more naturally than `films.film_id` (which you still have to do to distinguish from `film_categories.film_id`). Same reason why Ruby class `String` does not have method called `.string_length` - you know you're applying it to Strings.

Comment: Spolsky hallway test reveals: "id means *what*?"  id of what exactly, because there can be more than one id column in a table -- so, one gets to be id when the later was could be the more logical use?  There's nothing to gain using `film.id` when `film.film_id` solves problems.

Comment: @OMGPonies: And even in foreign keys, prefix is not necessarily a table name. To get a nonsimplistic example, in `people (id, first_name, last_name, father_id, mother_id, city_id)`, `cities (id, name, mayor_id)` - it is still clear what everything is. `cities.name` is the name of the city. `people.mother_id` will let you find a mother by her `id`.

Comment: @OMGPonies: If I have an ID that is not autoincrement, I will call it by its semantic value. I will only make `id` an autoincrement, semantics-free field, in absence of a better unique key. Thus, the question of "`id` means what" is exactly that - nothing. If I have social security numbers available, or whatever unique ID is intrinsic to a class, `people (ssn)` is what goes into the table. If you have to prefix `id`, then you need to prefix `name` too, and `address`... everything (as there's no logical cutoff where your hallway test stops working). If everything's prefixed, it's meaningless.

Comment: @OMGPonies: It's an enlightening discussion, to be sure - seeing how others perceive readability, for instance - but I'm pretty sure you won't change my mind about this.

Comment: Who said the prefix had to be a table name?  Likewise for your naming convention and how you interpret what I said.  When using table aliases, you'd never see `CITIES.name` - more like `c.name`.  Again - name of what?  First, last or middle?  I understand you're entrenched in your belief, but you might want to stop ignoring pertinent details like 3rd party, respected, design tests besides other facts.

Comment: @OMGPonies: I said the prefix would be a table name, and then I was clarifying what I meant (and it split into a next comment due to char limit). The difference between `c.name` and `cities.name` is no longer a discussion of database design but of coding style, and `cities.name` is clearly the name of the city. I do not feel I am ignoring anything: I like the hallway test, just questioon its applicability to this issue. Rather that I am engaged into an interesting and respectful discussion of difference of opinion, explaining my stance and asking pointed questions in order to understand yours.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Respectful, that is, until now - since I do not think I deserved a patronizing comment like your last sentence. Which shows me how much *you* think of *my* arguments. Thank you, I'll let myself out.

Comment: @Amadan: I addressed points you raised, and you shouldn't ignore my example of why the column being simply "id" isn't a wise decision.