# How to use COUNT on two tables with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, count

Guys I have three tables in SQL database. `tblTicketDetail`, `tblEngineer` and `tblTicket_Engineer` (a junction table for many-to-many relationship). What happens in my app is, when I generate a new ticket, the ticket is assigned to either one, two or three (max) engineers (thus the many-to-many relationship).

Following is the structure of tables :

**`tblTicketDetail`**

`+----------+---------------+--------+
| TicketID |     Desc      | Status |
+----------+---------------+--------+
|        1 | Description 1 |      1 |
|        2 | Description 2 |      0 |
|        3 | Description 3 |      1 |
+----------+---------------+--------+`

**`tblEngineer`**

`+------------+-------+
| EngineerID | Name  |
+------------+-------+
|          1 | Tom   |
|          2 | Harry |
|          3 | John  |
+------------+-------+`

**`tblTicket_Engineer`**

`+----------+------------+
 | TicketID | EngineerID |
 +----------+------------+
 |        1 |          1 |
 |        1 |          2 |
 |        1 |          3 |
 |        2 |          1 |
 |        3 |          1 |
 |        3 |          2 |
 +----------+------------+`

Now what I want to do is COUNT all `TicketID` which have the `status` of 1 and where the `EngineerID` should be specific (like for example 1).
I tried this query, but it generates two counts

```
SELECT  (
          SELECT COUNT(*) total
          FROM   tblTicketDetail WHERE Status = 1
        ) AS count1,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) total
          FROM   tblTicket_Engineer WHERE EngineerID = 1
        ) AS count2
```

In this case (where EngineerID = 1), the query should generate the count of 2. How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a join on your sub-query to get the ticket status and the sub-query should look like below:

```
      SELECT COUNT(*) total
      FROM   tblTicket_Engineer
      INNER JOIN  tblTicketDetail ON tblTicketDetail.TicketID = tblTicket_Engineer.TicketID AND tblTicketDetail.Status = 1
      WHERE tblTicket_Engineer.EngineerID = 1
```

Comment: He doesn't need two counts, so he doesn't need this as the subquery.  Although it should otherwise be fine.

Comment: This is working as per my requirement! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse just misunderstood the question as have suggested myself by the provided snippet that the op needs a count for all the tickets with status = 1 and then another count with engineer = 1. You are right there is no need for sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will help you

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM 
tblTicket inner join tblTicket_Engineer on 
(tblTicket.TicketID= tblTicket_Engineer.TicketID)
WHERE  tblTicket.Status = '1' 
AND tblTicket_Engineer.EngineerID = '1'
```

Comment: Yes, although I'd probably move `tblTicket_Engineer.EngineerID = '1'` into the join conditions.

Comment: Why are you using JOIN on two different IDs in the same table? `tblTicket_Engineer.EngineerID = tblTicket_Engineer.TicketID`.

Answer (score 2):

can you please try this query

```
SELECT COUNT(tblTicketDetail.TicketID) FROM tblTicketDetail 
JOIN tblTicket_Engineer ON  tblTicket_Engineer.TicketID = tblTicketDetail.TicketID    
WHERE tblTicket_Engineer.EngineerID = 1
AND tblTicketDetail.Status = 1
```

Comment: This query is also working as per requirement after tweaking a little bit! Thank you for your answer Khushbu!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
FROM   tblTicketDetail a, tblTicket_Engineer b
WHERE  a.TicketID = b.TicketID AND a.Status = 1 AND b.EngineerID = 1
```

Comment: You don't _strictly_ need `tblEngineer` for this query.  And please, avoid the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) in favor of explicit joins.

Comment: Working perfectly. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,this may help you.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total 
FROM tblTicketDetail as td, tblTicket_Engineer as te 
WHERE td.Status = 1 
      AND te.EngineerID = 1;
```

Comment: Nope, the result is `24` when the above query is executed.

Comment: You're heading in the right direction, but you've forgotten one important part - you need to tie engineers to the tickets they're working on!  This is why the recommendation is to not use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), in favor of explicitly listing your joins - it tends to make this problem more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a JOIN:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM   tblTicket NATURAL JOIN tblTicket_Engineer NATURAL JOIN tblEngineer
  WHERE  Status = 1 AND EngineerID = 1
```

In case your database engine does not support multiple NATURAL JOIN clauses, or you don't want to use them, you may resort to an explicit JOIN

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM   tblTicket INNER JOIN tblTicket_Engineer ON (TicketID)
         INNER JOIN tblEngineer ON (EngineedID)
  WHERE  Status = 1 AND EngineerID = 1
```

**NOTE**  Do not use NATURAL JOIN in *production environments*.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039719/is-natural-join-considered-harmful-in-production-environment).

Comment: Generates an error about using multiple NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: Then the problem is not generically related to SQL, but to a specific implementation.  Which is your RDBMS?

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid the use of `NATURAL JOIN` in any production database, because there are often columns that _shouldn't_ be joined, that should still have the same name - `createdOn` audit timestamp columns, any sort of `status` column, the list goes on.  Add in the many times that the columns you may want to join _won't_ have the same name - eg `employeeId` <-> `createdBy` audit column - and it doesn't appear that useful.