# MySQL foreign key/natural join

Tags: mysql

**Scenario:**

I've been trying to solve a problem where I wanted to make a natural join between two tables Artists and Albums, where Artists cointains a column ar_id that is the primary key and Albums contains a column also named ar_id where the foreign key in the Album table is ar_id and refers to Artists ar_id. There's a 1 to many relationship between the tables (one artist can have multiple albums).

**Problem:**

When I want to make a NATURAL JOIN between the two tables Artists and Albums it returns 0 rows, but when I use are normal JOIN with WHERE function it returns 18 rows as it should. So I guess the problem is the foreign key setup but I can't find the problem

**The select code with natural join (doesn't work):**

```
SELECT * FROM 
Artists NATURAL JOIN Albums;
```

**The select code with normal join where (does work):**

```
SELECT * FROM 
Artists JOIN Albums
WHERE CDReg.Artists.ar_id = CDReg.Albums.ar_id;
```

**DLL for the two tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Artists (
  ar_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  ge_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  country_code varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  start_year year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  end_year year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ge_id) REFERENCES Genres (ge_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Countries (code)
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE Albums (
  al_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  ar_id int,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  release_year year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ar_id) REFERENCES Artists(ar_id)
);
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

***[SOLVED]:***

I thought that natural join used the foreign key to join the tables but instead it uses all matching column names including the columns "`name`" (exsists in both tables), since there isn't any artists with an eponymous album title in the database the result was 0 rows. The solution was to use

```
SELECT * FROM 
Artists JOIN albums USING(ar_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> The NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN of two tables is defined to be semantically
>   equivalent to an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN with a USING clause that
>   names **all columns that exist in both tables**.

Both tables have a column `name` which is included in the natural join, making it fail for all combinations except for those where the artist and album names are the same (which I guess could happen).

You could use a join `FROM Artists JOIN albums USING (ar_id)` instead.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I thought it would be using the foreign key to that table only. Thanks it works fine with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The natural join probably use `name`in the join which leads to 0 results unless an artist has an eponymous album!

Anyhow you should [avoid natural join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039758/1980659) because, as you can see, they are less obvious.  Stick to the normal join version.