# Does `join` generate Cartesian product every time when using mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I' learned that when we use `join`(left join or right join, not inner join)  statement in mysql, mysql will generate a Cartesian Product as temporary table.

**But somebody told me that if the columns which used in `on` statement have index, 
Cartesian Product won't be generated.**

I'm not sure if he is right, because I can't find article or manual talks about it. It's he right?

By the way, somebody told me not to use `join` statement in production environment because it may have potential problem. But I think using `join` is quite no harm. And if we optimize the sql carefully, we will have no worry about performance problems. Should we forbid to use `join` in production environment? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect a bit of leg pulling. Certainly inner joins without on clauses will generate cartesian products as will cross joins and implicit (coma separated) joins. But to forbid the use of properly constructed joins is nonsense given that sql has no other method of linking tables (ignoring unions)

Comment: This may be similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039719/is-natural-join-considered-harmful-in-production-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cartesian product, aka, `CROSS JOIN`, happens whenever you have a `JOIN`, including `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `INNER`, without either an `ON` clause or the equivalent in the `WHERE` clause.

A temp table may or may not be generated by any kind of `JOIN`.  And it may or may not hit the disk.

`JOINs` in production.  Sure.  A well-indexed (etc) query is plenty fast.  And, when you need a `JOIN`, the alternatives, if any, may be worse.

From a *theoretical* point of view, a `JOIN` is performed thus:

1. Create the Cartesian product.
2. Toss any rows that don't match the `ON` and `WHERE` restrictions.
3. Move on to `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`.

In *reality*, the Optimizer takes all the short cuts it can think of.  A typical `JOIN` goes more like this:

1. Scan through one table, filtering out any rows not matching the `WHERE`.
2. Reach into the joined table using an index to find the 0 or 1 or several rows there.  Name:  NLJ - Nested Loop Join
3. Toss any *more* rows that don't match the rest of the `ON` and `WHERE` restrictions.
4. etc.

As for `LEFT` and `RIGHT` -- Don't use them *unless* you need to get a result row even if the row is missing from the 'right' or 'left', respectively, table.  It confuses the user and makes the Optimizer work harder to decide that you really meant `INNER JOIN`.

In MySQL, the keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are essentially ignored.  The existence of a suitable `ON` or `WHERE` controls what type of `JOIN` it is.