# Syntax Error when trying to make a comparison with the same relation generated by a natural join

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-join

I am trying to write a query for a `MySQL` database which compares two tuples within the same relation that is generated by a natural join.

The database has relations author and author_number, which can be natural joined to create a relation that shows all authors as well as all of their phone numbers.

I am trying to write a query that returns only tuples for authors that share the same phone number.

I have written a query that I believe has the right idea behind it, but I have done something wrong because I am getting a syntax error when I try to run it.

Here is the query I currently have which I thought would work:

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, A.pNumber
FROM (author NATURAL JOIN author_number AS A), (author NATURAL JOIN author_number AS B)
WHERE A.pNumber = B.pNumber;
```

The query is giving the error:

> `ERROR 1066 (42000) at line 60 in file: 'QueryLib.sql': Not unique table/alias: 'author'`

Also my original query didn't have the `A.first_name, etc.` in the `SELECT` clause, it just had `first_name, etc.` but I got the same error message.

Comment: You are mixing implicit join and natural join in a weird manner, this giving syntax errors. Give sample data in the two tables, and correspondence expected output. And if problem is solvable by regular JOIN, i would go with them..

Comment: Read [the MySQL manual re join grammar & semantics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). The aliases here are author (implicitly), A, author (implicitly) & B. One can't use the same alias twice. A & B alias author_number. Seems maybe you want (SELECT * FROM author NATURAL JOIN author_number) AS A & similarly for B. PS Please read & act on [mre]. PS Normally when using NATURAL JOIN we would expect to rename columns via a subselect. Aliases are for non-NATURAL JOINs. PS One doesn't need to use both NATURAL & non-NATURAL JOINs to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that natural joins are considered harmful: [Is NATURAL (JOIN) considered harmful in production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039719/is-natural-join-considered-harmful-in-production-environment). It is better to write an explicit inner join.

Returning to your question. You need to refer to individual tables from the natural join. For example:

```
SELECT
  A1.first_name, A1.last_name, AN1.phone_number
FROM
  Author A1 NATURAL JOIN AuthorNumber AN1,
  Author A2 NATURAL JOIN AuthorNumber AN2
WHERE
  AN1.phone_number = AN2.phone_number AND
  NOT (A1.first_name = A2.first_name AND A1.last_name = A2.last_name);
```

**Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2951/7.

Comment: Please note that the people who consider Natural JOIN harmful are the people who don't understand the Relational Model, and aren't competent to design schemas for it.