# Natural Join with dissimilar column names in Oracle and Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, join

I am using Oracle Database, but I also checked the scenario on PostgreSQL. I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE departments (
  dept_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  dept_name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_name VARCHAR(255),
  department_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments(dept_id)
);
```

As you can see, the foreign key column in the department table is named department_id with a datatype of INT, whereas the referencing column in the employees table is named dept_id and has a datatype of INT. They neither share the same name nor have the same datatype.

Then I wrote this natural join statement:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
NATURAL JOIN departments;
```

Surprisingly, it gave me the result instead of an error. Considering the definition, one might naturally expect an error in this situation.

So, I thought maybe it's because of the foreign key reference, so I removed it:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_C008253;
```

Then I ran the same query again, and once more, it provided the result instead of an error.

My question is, why am I getting a result and not an error? The definition says NATURAL JOIN needs columns with the same name, so there should be an error, right?

Comment: "They neither share the same name nor have the same datatype." Although the names differ, the DDL in your question show the same data type of `int`.

Comment: Avoid natural joins. They are a time bomb waiting to explode if you add new columns to either table.

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 5):

You're effectively joining on an empty list of conditions - [`natural join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) is based purely on the column *names* with no regard for any actual foreign key references in place. Here, it finds no matching column names and - similar to how omitting a list of conditions in a `where` works like `where true` - no conditions for a `join` works like `join...on true`. It's even put that way [in the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.3.2.8.2)

> `NATURAL` is a shorthand form of `USING`: it forms a `USING` list consisting of all column names that appear in both input tables. As with `USING`, these columns appear only once in the output table. If there are no common column names, `NATURAL JOIN` behaves like `JOIN ... ON TRUE`, producing a cross-product join.

So you end up getting the same thing a `cross join`, a comma `,`, a `join...on true` would get you, and all of these are [perfectly valid expressions](https://dbfiddle.uk/UvZuRCL5).

What you encountered is one of the reasons the use of `natural join` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6039719/5298879).

Comment: I don't use natural joins but I would have expected the engine to crash the query in the absence of matching column names.

Comment: does it mean if it does not find a common column it will behave like a cross join?

Comment: @sudhirkaushik Yes, exactly.