# Amazon RSQL concat of two tables with 2 shared columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, concatenation, amazon-redshift

I have such an example of tables:

table1:

| col 1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x1 | asdc |
| 2 | b | x2 | czxa |
| 3 | c | x3 | xfsdaa |

table2:

| col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| l | x56 |
| q | x99 |

All I want is to receive such a final concatenation

| col 1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x1 | asdc |
| 2 | b | x2 | czxa |
| 3 | c | x3 | xfsdaa |
| null | l | x56 | null |
| null | q | x99 | null |

How can I make it in RSQL (postgresql based SQL)? I thought about selecting all columns from the first table, then `union all` and use `NULL AS col1 [...] NULL AS col4` in the place of missing columns, but in real data I have dozens of columns so the code won't look great with it.

Is there some other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind reordered columns you can get away with a [`natural full outer join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN):

> `USING` clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an equality comparison for each one. For example, joining `T1` and `T2` with `USING (a, b)` produces the join condition `ON T1.a = T2.a AND T1.b = T2.b`.

> `NATURAL` is a shorthand form of `USING`: it forms a `USING` list consisting of all column names that appear in both input tables. As with `USING`, these columns appear only once in the output table. If there are no common column names, `NATURAL JOIN` behaves like `JOIN ... ON TRUE`, producing a cross-product join.

Which means it'll deduplicate columns with matching names, without you having to name them or even know them. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/XmxUxOSP)

```sql
select * from table1 natural full outer join table2;
```

| col2 | col3 | col1 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x1 | 1 | asdc |
| b | x2 | 2 | czxa |
| c | x3 | 3 | xfsdaa |
| l | x56 | *null* | *null* |
| q | x99 | *null* | *null* |

Problem is, matching values in columns with matching names will be joined together. It might as well be the desired effect but if it's not, you can force the mismatch using the fact that joining on *`null`* values results in a mismatch:

```sql
select * 
from (select tableoid::regclass,null as force_mismatch,* from table1) a
natural full outer join
     (select tableoid::regclass,null as force_mismatch,* from table2) b;
```

| tableoid | force_mismatch | col2 | col3 | col1 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | *null* | a | x1 | 1 | asdc |
| table1 | *null* | b | x2 | 2 | czxa |
| table1 | *null* | c | x3 | 3 | xfsdaa |
| table2 | *null* | c | x3 | *null* | *null* |
| table2 | *null* | l | x56 | *null* | *null* |
| table2 | *null* | q | x99 | *null* | *null* |

I've added [`tableoid` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-TABLEOID) only to show `(c, x3)` was in both tables. It potentially offers some added utility and you can force the mismatch using just that, but otherwise it's enough to add a constantly *`null`* column with the same name on both sides.

Keep in mind that `natural join` is a [sensitive topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78092759/5298879): it's risky and typically advised against.

That being said, what you proposed with the [`UNION`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_example_unionall_query.html) clause and *`null`* constants wherever you want to skip a field is the most obvious, but it should also perform better: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rD-TYX9x)

```
create table table1(col1, col2, col3, col4) as values
 (1,    'a',    'x1',   'asdc')
,(2,    'b',    'x2',   'czxa')
,(3,    'c',    'x3',   'xfsdaa');

create table table2(col2,col3) as values
 ('l',  'x56')
,('q',  'x99');

select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1
union all
select null, col2, col3, null from table2;
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x1 | asdc |
| 2 | b | x2 | czxa |
| 3 | c | x3 | xfsdaa |
| *null* | l | x56 | *null* |
| *null* | q | x99 | *null* |

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like Union and have multiple tables then you can use `full outer join`

[`db-fiddle`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2QCzGev7ZkaKwPUJKMYLuD/0)

**Query**

```
select col1, 
    coalesce(t1.col2,t2.col2) as col2, 
    coalesce(t1.col3,t2.col3) as col3, 
    col4
from t1
full outer join t2
on 1=2;
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | l | x56 |  |
|  | q | x99 |  |
| 1 | a | x1 | asdc |
| 2 | b | x2 | czxa |
| 3 | c | x3 | xfsdaa |

---